# my bullets use raycasts to detects everything they miss in a physics update but it doesnt do damage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.Internal;
using static UnityEngine.GraphicsBuffer;
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Header("References")]
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;

    [Header("Attributes")]
    [SerializeField] private float BulletSpeed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask Enemies;

    public Transform target;
    public Transform StartPoint;
    public int Damage;
    public float ProjecDistance;
    public int Pierce;
    private int Pierced = 0;
    private List<int> HitName = new List<int>();
    private void EnemyHit(RaycastHit2D Hits)
    {
        Hits.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyMovement>().Damage(Damage);
        HitName.Add(Hits.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyMovement>().GetInstanceID());
        Pierced += 1;
    }
    void Start()
    {
        Vector2 direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
        Vector2 vector = new Vector2(direction.x, direction.y).normalized;

        rb.velocity = vector * BulletSpeed;

        RaycastHit2D[] Hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(transform.position, transform.forward, rb.velocity.magnitude * Time.deltaTime, Enemies);
        for (int i = 0; i < Hits.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Pierced >= Pierce)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
            if (HitName == null || !HitName.Contains(Hits[i].collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyMovement>().GetInstanceID()))
            {
                EnemyHit(Hits[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Vector2.Distance(StartPoint.position, transform.position) >= ProjecDistance)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        RaycastHit2D[] Hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(transform.position, transform.forward, rb.velocity.magnitude * Time.deltaTime, Enemies);
        for (int i = 0; i < Hits.Length; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(Hits[i]);
            if (Pierced >= Pierce)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
            if (HitName == null || !HitName.Contains(Hits[i].collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyMovement>().GetInstanceID()))
            {
                EnemyHit(Hits[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried making the raycast infinite length but it still doesn't do damage to prefab enemies that it's supposed to hit, so there's something wrong with the raycasts I'm doing or how I'm detecting game objects with my raycasts.
I don't know how else to make bullets that pierce as well as moving really fast, right now my bullets have a speed of 50.

Also, all values are given to the bullet on initialization

Comment: I don't understand the question. Shouldn't bullets damage what they hit, not what they miss?

Comment: what is it not doing damage to? its not overly clear

Comment: your movement direction `target.position - transform.position` might be quite different from `transform.forward` .. also you use a maximum distance of `rb.velocity.magnitude * Time.deltaTime` .. this is a ridiculously small one ... assume a frame-rate of 60 frames per second this value will be about `0.017 * BulletSpeed` ...

Comment: also tbh storing the instanceIDs seems a bit redundant .. the `EnemyMovement` or even the `collider.gameObject` reference already is unique ;) .. and the check for `HitName == null` ... why should it ever be `null`?

Comment: Why use raycast at all? Seems you could simply use e.g. `OnCollisionEnter2D`/`OnTriggerEnter2D` instead ...

Comment: Use Debug.DrawRay to show you visually where your rays are.

Comment: Palle Due when it moves too fast that during a physics update its usually not touching anything so I'm using a raycast to detect what it missed in between physics updates

Comment: derHugo I'm storing the InstanceID because every prefab enemy has the same script and if I don't it hits the enemies multiple times, at first HitName is null until it hits something. I made the bullet point the same way as the turret that shoots it which points towards the enemy. I've tried using OncollisionEnter2D but it doesn't detect the hits.

Comment: Rocketman Dan
i have
its where i expected it to be